# How report progress of background workers in an array

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a background progress (factory) which creates more background processes (workers) to split up the work load.
I need each worker to report it's progress to the factory and the factory to report it to the GUI.
For the factory I can use

```
Factory.ReportProgress(value);
```

But I can't seem to refer to my workers from inside the DoWork method.
My factory DoWork:

```
private void Factory_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{            
    BackgroundWorker[] Workers = new BackgroundWorker[ThreadCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
    {
        BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        Workers[i] = Worker;

        Worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        Worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;

        Worker.RunWorkerAsync(argument: TimesToRun);

        Progress++;
        Factory.ReportProgress(Progress);
    }
}
```

My Worker DoWork:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.Argument; i++)
    {
        if (Running)
        {
            //Do work
            Thread.Sleep(10);                    
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the worker report progress to the factory each time it completes 1 for loop?

Comment: You need to use the `.ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorker` instance. The instance is the `object sender`. Ref [BackgroundWorker DoWork Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to upvote my comment then :D

Comment: Sorry I'm new and only have 6 reputation and you need 15 to upvote comments.

Comment: I've posted my comment as the Answer.

Comment: _"I need each worker to report it's progress to the factory"_ -- then do that. See marked duplicates. You just need to call `ReportProgress()` in each worker, since your factory object has already subscribed to each worker's `ProgressChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can report progress by calling the `ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorker` instance inside the `DoWork` method. The active BackgroundWorker instance is the `object sender` argument.

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.Argument; i++)
    {
        if (Running)
        {
            //Do work
            Thread.Sleep(10);  
            //Report Progress
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
}
```

See documentation on microsoft Website : [BackgroundWorker DoWork Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork?view=netframework-4.8)